# How to find specific id's from an array

Tags: php

i need to display the oldest 10 movies from this array. After that i need to make a list with them and each one to be a link to their pages. I need to find their id, to display all the details of the film.
How can i found the id's of these specific 10 movies from the array?

```
<?php $movies = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yegor-sytnyk/movies-list/master/db.json'))->movies;?>
```

Comment: Can you post output of that json ?

Comment: here is the link for the output:

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yegor-sytnyk/movies-list/master/db.json

Comment: @Alex98 Welcome to SO, you need to get the oldest 10 movies and id for each movies?

Comment: yes;) and then to make a list with the movies. And these links to send me to the movie page with all the details of the movie. I have already these pages, But i cant find these 10 movies and the id for each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$movies = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yegor-sytnyk/movies-list/master/db.json'))->movies;


// Sorts your array by the year in ascending order
uasort($movies, function($a, $b) {
    return $a->year > $b->year;
});

// Drops all but the first 10 movies
$movies = array_slice($movies, 0, 10);

 // See that it works :)
 echo "<pre>";
 var_dump($movies);
 echo "</pre>";

 // Access each movie's ID
 foreach($movies as $movie){
    echo $movie->id;
 }
```

Comment: From your list, that identifies the following 10 movies (from oldest to newest): All Quiet on the Western Front, Casablanca, The Third Man, Sunset Boulevard, Rear Window, 12 Angry Men, Vertigo, North by Northwest, Psycho, and To Kill a Mockingbird.

Comment: You're welcome :)  The json_decode gives you an array of objects. So `$movies` contained everything you needed. `uasort()` is a little tricky (https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_uasort.asp). But it's comparing the years to each other and rearranging ordering them. And then `array_slice()` just takes the array movies and grabs the 10 elements, starting at 0. Then you can access the id like you would in any object by moving through the array. I hope this explanation makes it clear so you can continue to improve your project! (ie you could access the title/etc). Happy coding :)

Comment: Yes, i have already done a lot of things using your explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Comparator function used for comparator 
// year of two movie object
function comparator($object1, $object2)
{
    return $object1->year > $object2->year;
}

$output = file_get_contents("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yegor-sytnyk/movies-list/master/db.json");


$data = json_decode($output);

$movies = $data->movies;

// ordering array asc order by year
usort($movies, 'comparator');

// first 10 movie 
var_dump(array_slice($movies, 0, 10));
die;
```